# How do I correctly decode unicode parameters passed to a servlet

Tags: java, unicode, servlets

Suppose I have:

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com/" target="_yahoo" 
    title="Yahoo!&#8482;" onclick="return gateway(this);">Yahoo!</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function gateway(lnk) {
    window.open(SERVLET +
        '?external_link=' + encodeURIComponent(lnk.href) +
        '&external_target=' + encodeURIComponent(lnk.target) +
        '&external_title=' + encodeURIComponent(lnk.title));
    return false;
}
</script>
```

I have confirmed `external_title` gets encoded as `Yahoo!%E2%84%A2` and passed to `SERVLET`. If in `SERVLET` I do:

```
Writer writer = response.getWriter();
writer.write(request.getParameter("external_title"));
```

I get *Yahoo!â„¢* in the browser. If I manually switch the browser character encoding to UTF-8, it changes to *Yahoo!<sup>TM</sup>* (which is what I want).

So I figured the encoding I was sending to the browser was wrong (it was `Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1`). I changed `SERVLET` to:

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
Writer writer = response.getWriter();
writer.write(request.getParameter("external_title"));
```

Now the browser character encoding is UTF-8, but it outputs *Yahoo!â¢* and I can't get the browser to render the correct character at all.

My question is: is there some combination of `Content-type` and/or `new String(request.getParameter("external_title").getBytes(), "UTF-8");` and/or something else that will result in *Yahoo!<sup>TM</sup>* appearing in the `SERVLET` output?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are nearly there. EncodeURIComponent correctly encodes to UTF-8, which is what you should always use in a URL today.

The problem is that the submitted query string is getting mutilated on the way into your server-side script, because getParameter() uses ISO-8559-1 instead of UTF-8. This stems from Ancient Times before the web settled on UTF-8 for URI/IRI, but it's rather pathetic that the Servlet spec hasn't been updated to match reality, or at least provide a reliable, supported option for it.

(There is request.setCharacterEncoding in Servlet 2.3, but it doesn't affect query string parsing, and if a single parameter has been read before, possibly by some other framework element, it won't work at all.)

So you need to futz around with container-specific methods to get proper UTF-8, often involving stuff in server.xml. This totally sucks for distributing web apps that should work anywhere. For Tomcat see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Character+Encoding and also [What's the difference between "URIEncoding" of Tomcat, Encoding Filter and request.setCharacterEncoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944802/whats-the-difference-between-uriencoding-of-tomcat-encoding-filter-and-reque).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. At least I know I'm not crazy. I tried request.setCharacterEncoding() while looking for a solution and as you said, it didn't seem to do anything to help resolve my problem.

Comment: And here is a link for Jetty if anyone is using it (by default Jetty 6+ uses UTF-8 unless configured otherwise): http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/International+Characters+and+Character+Encodings

Comment: `request.getParameter("name")` prints as `ÏÎ·Î³ÏÏÏÏÎ·`. `request.getQueryString()` prints as `name=%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%B3%CF%81%CF%84%CF%83%CF%82%CE%B7` - which if passed to `URLDecoder.decode()` is decoded fine. Could you please comment on _why does not `getParameter()` return the percent encoded string_ ? Is not ISO-8559-1 a superset of ASCII ?

Comment: `getParameter` is intended to take care of decoding the input for you - browsers encode form values with percents when submitted so you have to decode them to get the user's input. There has to be some encoding used to turn the bytes in the input into characters, and browsers don't always use the same encoding. Unfortunately Servlet chooses one for you, it doesn't choose well, and it doesn't let you override that choice - unlike `URLDecoder.decode` there is no `enc` argument.

Comment: If you want the percent-encoded content from the raw URL, use `getQueryString()` and parse it yourself instead of letting Servlet do it.

Answer (score 21):

I got the same problem and solved it by decoding `Request.getQueryString()` using URLDecoder(), and after extracting my parameters.

```
String[] Parameters = URLDecoder.decode(Request.getQueryString(), 'UTF-8')
                       .splitat('&');
```

Comment: Handling the query string yourself is a good idea to deal with the problems in `getParameter`, however this isn't quite right: it should URL-decode *after* splitting the components apart, rather than before. The code above would fail for any use of the `&` character in parameters (encoded to `%26`), or `=` in parameter names (`%3D`).

Comment: what about POST parameters ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128436/query-string-manipulation-in-java/ for several manual decoding examples.

Answer (score 18):

There is way to do it in java (no fiddling with `server.xml`)

Do not work :

```
protected static final String CHARSET_FOR_URL_ENCODING = "UTF-8";

String uname = request.getParameter("name");
System.out.println(uname);
// ÏÎ·Î³ÏÏÏÏÎ·
uname = request.getQueryString();
System.out.println(uname);
// name=%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%B3%CF%81%CF%84%CF%83%CF%82%CE%B7
uname = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("name"),
        CHARSET_FOR_URL_ENCODING);
System.out.println(uname);
// ÏÎ·Î³ÏÏÏÏÎ· // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
uname = URLDecoder.decode(
        "name=%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%B3%CF%81%CF%84%CF%83%CF%82%CE%B7",
        CHARSET_FOR_URL_ENCODING);
System.out.println("query string decoded : " + uname);
// query string decoded : name=τηγρτσςη
uname = URLDecoder.decode(new String(request.getParameter("name")
        .getBytes()), CHARSET_FOR_URL_ENCODING);
System.out.println(uname);
// ÏÎ·Î³ÏÏÏÏÎ· // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

<strike>Works</strike> :

```
final String name = URLDecoder
        .decode(new String(request.getParameter("name").getBytes(
                "iso-8859-1")), CHARSET_FOR_URL_ENCODING);
System.out.println(name);
// τηγρτσςη
```

Worked but [will break if default encoding != utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913264/eclipse-vs-tomcat-deployment-exported-war-partially-fails-while-the-project) - try this instead (omit the call to decode() it's not needed):

```
final String name = new String(request.getParameter("name").getBytes("iso-8859-1"),
        CHARSET_FOR_URL_ENCODING);
```

---

As I said above if the `server.xml` is messed with as in :

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                     redirectPort="8443"  URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

(notice the *`URIEncoding="UTF-8"`*) the code above will break (cause the `getBytes("iso-8859-1")` should read `getBytes("UTF-8")`). So for a bullet proof solution you have to get the value of the `URIEncoding` attribute. This unfortunately seems to be container specific - even worse container version specific. For tomcat 7 you'd need something like :

```
import javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException;
import javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException;
import javax.management.MBeanException;
import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.MBeanServerFactory;
import javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.ReflectionException;

import org.apache.catalina.Server;
import org.apache.catalina.Service;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;

public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

    // ...
    static String CHARSET_FOR_URI_ENCODING; // the `URIEncoding` attribute
    static {
        MBeanServer mBeanServer = MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(null).get(
            0);
        ObjectName name = null;
        try {
            name = new ObjectName("Catalina", "type", "Server");
        } catch (MalformedObjectNameException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Server server = null;
        try {
            server = (Server) mBeanServer.getAttribute(name, "managedResource");
        } catch (AttributeNotFoundException | InstanceNotFoundException
                | MBeanException | ReflectionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Service[] services = server.findServices();
        for (Service service : services) {
            for (Connector connector : service.findConnectors()) {
                System.out.println(connector);
                String uriEncoding = connector.getURIEncoding();
                System.out.println("URIEncoding : " + uriEncoding);
                boolean use = connector.getUseBodyEncodingForURI();
                // TODO : if(use && connector.get uri enc...)
                CHARSET_FOR_URI_ENCODING = uriEncoding;
                // ProtocolHandler protocolHandler = connector
                // .getProtocolHandler();
                // if (protocolHandler instanceof Http11Protocol
                // || protocolHandler instanceof Http11AprProtocol
                // || protocolHandler instanceof Http11NioProtocol) {
                // int serverPort = connector.getPort();
                // System.out.println("HTTP Port: " + connector.getPort());
                // }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And still you need to tweak this for multiple connectors (check the commented out parts). Then you would use something like :

```
new String(parameter.getBytes(CHARSET_FOR_URI_ENCODING), CHARSET_FOR_URL_ENCODING);
```

Still this may fail ([IIUC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544965/why-new-stringbytes-enc-getbytesenc-does-not-return-the-original-byte-array)) if `parameter = request.getParameter("name");` decoded with CHARSET_FOR_URI_ENCODING was corrupted so the bytes I get with getBytes() were not the original ones (that's why "iso-8859-1" is used by default - [it will preserve the bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925458/iso-8859-1-encoding-and-binary-data-preservation)). You can get rid of it all by manually parsing the query string in the lines of:

```
URLDecoder.decode(request.getQueryString().split("=")[1],
        CHARSET_FOR_URL_ENCODING);
```

<sub>I am still looking for the place in the docs where it is mentioned that `request.getParameter("name")` does call `URLDecoder.decode()`  instead of returning the `%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%B3%CF%81%CF%84%CF%83%CF%82%CE%B7` string ?  A link in the source would be much appreciated.

<del>Also how can I pass as the parameter's value the string, say, `%CE` ?</del> => see comment : `parameter=%25CE`</sub>

Comment: If you want to pass `%CE` you simply encode it, so `parameter=%25CE`

Comment: yes, I prefer leaving platform configurations untouched as much as possible. I'll enter the ISO-Charset in my custom servlets configuration (custom properties in tomcat/conf), so I can change it at runtime or even adjust it in new server deployments - if needed. Specifications should always rule over customizations.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the data mutilation happens in the request, i.e. the declared encoding of the request does not match the one that is actually used for the data.

What does `request.getCharacterEncoding()` return?

I don't really know how JavaScript handles encodings or how to make it use a specific one.

You need to make sure that encodings are used correctly at all stages - do NOT try to "fix" the data by using `new String()` an `getBytes()` at a point where it has already been encoded incorrectly.

**Edit:** It may help to have the origin page (the one with the Javascript) also encoded in UTF-8 and declared as such in its Content-Type. Then I believe Javascript may default to using UTF-8 for its request - but this is not definite knowledge, just guesswork.

Comment: request.getCharacterEncoding() is returning ISO-8859-1. So I think the problem is that encodeURIComponent() encodes the value as UTF-8, but it is getting mangled by the request encoding of ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use javascript to manipulate the text further.

```
<div id="test">a</div>
<script>
var a = document.getElementById('test');
alert(a.innerHTML);
a.innerHTML = decodeURI("Yahoo!%E2%84%A2");
alert(a.innerHTML);
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, decodeURIComponent() returns the correct value, but only if I extract the value from the URL in JavaScript. If I attempt to decodeURIComponent('<%= request.getParameter("external_title") %>'); I don't get the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can get the following to work:

```
encodeURIComponent(escape(lnk.title))
```

That gives me `%25u2122` (for &#8482) or `%25AE` (for &#174), which will decode to `%u2122` and `%AE` respectively in the servlet.

I should then be able to turn %u2122 into `'\u2122'` and %AE into `'\u00AE'` relatively easily using `(char) (base-10 integer value of %uXXXX or %XX)` in a match and replace loop using regular expressions.

i.e. - match `/%u([0-9a-f]{4})/i`, extract the matching subexpression, convert it to base-10, turn it into a char and append it to the output, then do the same with `/%([0-9a-f]{2})/i`

Comment: This is one possible encoding scheme you could use to get around the Servlet Parameter Charset Problem. (One that didn't use the dodgy JavaScript escape() function might be better.) But any such isn't the standard way to pass parameters in, so any other scripts/forms wouldn't be able to talk to it.

Comment: I agree that using escape() isn't the best option, but I'd rather not  write my own encoding routine in JavaScript. I've tested my design using escape() in IE6, 7 & 8, Firefox 2 & 3, Opera 9.6, Safari for Windows 3.2.1 and Google Chrome and it works consistently for those browsers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in certain versions of Jetty that makes it parse higher number UTF-8 characters incorrectly.  If your server accepts arabic letters correctly but not emoji, that's a sign you have a version with this problem, since arabic is not in ISO-8859-1, but is in the lower range of UTF-8 characters ("lower" meaning java will represent it in a single char).

I updated from version 7.2.0.v20101020 to version 7.5.4.v20111024 and this fixed the problem; I can now use the getParameter(String) method instead of having to parse it myself.

If you're really curious, you can dig into your version of org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8StringBuilder.append(byte) and see whether it correctly adds multiple chars to the string when the utf-8 code is high enough or if, as in 7.2.0, it simply casts an int to a char and appends.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all I get to know about encoding decoding of default character set that use in tomcat, jetty
I use this method to solve my problems using google guava

```
        String str = URLDecoder.decode(request.getQueryString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        final Map<String, String> map = Splitter.on('&').trimResults().withKeyValueSeparator("=").split(str);
        System.out.println(map);
        System.out.println(map.get("aung"));
        System.out.println(map.get("aa"));
```