# Why new String(bytes, enc).getBytes(enc) does not return the original byte array?

Tags: java

I made the following "simulation":

```
byte[] b = new byte[256];

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i ++) {
    b[i] = (byte) (i - 128);
}
byte[] transformed = new String(b, "cp1251").getBytes("cp1251");

for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i ++) {
    if (b[i] != transformed[i]) {
        System.out.println("Wrong : " + i);
    }
}
```

For `cp1251` this outputs only one wrong byte - at position 25.
For `KOI8-R` - all fine.
For `cp1252` - 4 or 5 differences.

What is the reason for this and how can this be overcome?

I know it is *wrong* to represent byte arrays as strings in whatever encoding, but it is a requirement of the protocol of a payment provider, so I don't have a choice.

**Update:** representing it in `ISO-8859-1` works, and I'll use it for the `byte[]` part, and `cp1251` for the textual part, so the question remains only out of curiousity

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some of the "bytes" are not supported in the target set - they are replaced with the `?` character. When you convert back, `?` is normally converted to the byte value 63 - which isn't what it was before.

Comment: Awesome. I was actually looking for the answer in .NET but they are both similar enough in behaviour that I gleaned it from this. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

> What is the reason for this

The reason is that character encodings are not necesarily [bijective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective) and there is no good reason to expect them to be. Not all bytes or byte sequences are legal in all encodings, and usually illegal sequences are decoded to some sort of placeholder character like '?' or [U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), which of course does not produce the same bytes when re-encoded.

Additionally, some encodings may map some legal different byte sequences to the same string.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that both cp1251 and cp1252 have byte values that do not correspond to defined characters; i.e. they are "unmappable".

The javadoc for `String(byte[], String)` says this:

> The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the given charset is unspecified. The `CharsetDecoder` class should be used when more control over the decoding process is required.

Other constructors say this:

> This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with this charset's default replacement string.

If you see this kind of thing happening in practice it indicates that either you are using the wrong character set, or you've been given some bad data.  Either way, it is probably not a good idea to carry on as if there was no problem.

I've been trying to figure out if there is a way to get a CharsetDecoder to "preserve" unmappable characters, and I don't think it is possible unless you are willing to implementing a custom decoder/encoder pair.  But I've also concluded that it does not make sense to even try.  It is (theoretically) wrong map those unmappable characters to real Unicode code points.  And if you do, how is your application going to  handle them?

Answer (score 3):

Actually there shall be one difference: a byte of value 24 is converted to a `char` of value `0xFFFD`; that's the "Unicode replacement character", used for untranslatable bytes. When converted back, you get a question mark (value 63).

In CP1251, the code 24 means "end of input" and cannot be part of a proper string, which is why Java deems it as "untranslatable".

Answer (score 2):

Historical reason: in the ancient character encodings (EBCDIC, ASCII)  the first 32 codes have special 'control' meaning and they may not map to readable characters. Examples: backspace, bell, carriage return. Newer character encoding standards usually inherit this and they don't define Unicode characters for every one of the first 32 positions. Java characters are Unicode.