# decode encode between String and byte in java

Tags: java

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 1, -1 };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new String(bytes, "UTF-8").getBytes("UTF-8")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));
```

output:

```
[1, -17, -65, -67]
[1, -1]
```

why???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544965/why-new-stringbytes-enc-getbytesenc-does-not-return-the-original-byte-array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your byte array isn't a valid UTF-8-encoded string... so the string you get from

```
new String(bytes, "UTF-8")
```

contains U+0001 (for the first byte) and U+FFFD to signify bad data in the second byte. When that string is encoded using UTF-8, you get the byte pattern shown.

Basically you shouldn't try to interpret arbitrary binary data as if it were encoded in a particular encoding. If you want to represent arbitrary binary data as a string, use something like base64.

Comment: thanks Jon. 
But I am not familiar with base64, how does base64 support all byte in case lossing data?

Comment: @seven: I'm not sure exactly what you mean - but it converts opaque binary data to just ASCII, which is generally easy to transport.

Comment: Is it possible some bytes, which are not included in ASCII Alphabet, can not convert to ASCII? thanks.

Comment: @seven: No, the whole point of base64 is that it takes *any* set of bytes and converts it to ASCII. That's why it ends up being longer (4 characters for every 3 bytes).

Answer (score 2):

-1 is not a valid UTF-8 encoded character. [-17, -65, -67] is most likely the byte representation of the [replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replacement_character) that gets substituted.

Answer (score 0):

String isn't a container for binary data. It is a container for char. -1 isn't a legal value for a char. There's no reason why what you're doing should ever work. Ergo, don't do it.