# Why GZIPInputStream takes quite long time?

Tags: java, compression, gzip, gzipstream, gzipinputstream

```
System.out.println("Input String length : " + str.length());
System.out.println("SWB==="+sw.getTime());
byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(str);
System.out.println("SWB==="+sw.getTime());
GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis));
String outStr = "";
String line;
while ((line=bf.readLine())!=null) {
     outStr += line;
}
System.out.println("SWB==="+sw.getTime());
System.out.println("Output String lenght : " + outStr.length());
```

The above code prints

```
SWB===1
SWB===4
SWB===27052
Output String lenght : 1750825
```

But the compression of the same string takes quite short time (less than 100ms). What am i doing wrong here ? (other than my bad way of debug comments)

Comment: Try using `StringBuilder` instead of `outStr += line`.

Comment: I found this to work faster : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10572491/393639

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
String line;
while ((line=bf.readLine())!=null) {
     outStr += line;
}
```

Each `String` concatenation will implicitly create a `StringBuilder` to append the 2 strings, then call `toString()` method on it.

Use a single `StringBuilder` to drastically speed this up:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(65536); // Consider a large initial size
String line
while ((line=bf.readLine())!=null) {
     sb.append(line);
}

// OutString is in the sb StringBuilder
String outStr = sb.toString();
```

Also consider a large initial `StringBuilder` size to even minimize the internal reallocations. In the example I used 64KB, but if you know your result `String` will be much bigger, you can even safely use multiple MBs.

Also consider not calling `toString()` on the result if you don't need it. `StringBuilder` implements `CharSequence` and many methods accept `CharSequence` as well as `String`s.