# Android Volley too big string in JsonRequest

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am using volley to send some pretty big JsonRequest, and when the Json object calls toString, I receive an java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. It is on Nexus 7 2013 Android 4.4

```
JsonRequest request = new JsonRequest<ResponseData>(
            method,
            url,
            EntryJsonObject.toString(),
            responseListener,
            errorListener)



java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:132)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:124)
        at org.json.JSONStringer.string(JSONStringer.java:344)
        at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:252)
        at org.json.JSONArray.writeTo(JSONArray.java:602)
        at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:233)
        at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:672)
        at org.json.JSONObject.toString(JSONObject.java:641)
        at com.dis.project1.restclient.Api.putInput(Api.java:205)
```

Any idea how to build the final String with all Json data so that I will not receive OutOfMemory. String has about 40 MBytes. It is a bit complex structure with 3 JsonArrays with a coupple of objects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add **android:largeHeap="true"** line in your application
AndroidMenifest.xml . It might help you.

Like :

```
<application
        android:name=""
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        **android:largeHeap="true"**
         ...
    </application>
```

Comment: Well this is not exactly how I wanted to solve this, but it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to compress your string?

Pseudocode:

```
byte[] compressedBytes = compress(bigJsonString);
String base64String    = Base64.encode(compressedBytes );
[...]
byte[] origCompressedBytes  = Base64.decode(base64String);
```

[How can I easily compress and decompress Strings to/from byte arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10572491/1614378)

---

You could also try [Json Streaming](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming)

> Most applications should use only the object model API. JSON streaming
>   is useful in just a few situations:
>
> - When it is impossible or undesirable to load the entire object model
>     into memory. This is most relevant on mobile platforms where memory is
>     limited.
> - When it is necessary to read or write a document before it is
>     completely available.