# Forcing Unicode in byte variable

Tags: java, string, unicode, byte, arrays

I recently discovered that you convert a String to a byte array in the following manner:

```
String S = "ab";
byte arr[] = S.getBytes();
```

Now, I tried with String `"\u9999"` and the answer was `[63]`. I thought it would be 9999 (mod 128) = 15 which is actually what we get if we do `byte b = 9999`. What is the reason behind the 63?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the answer was [63]"? What answer?

Comment: I mean `arr[] = {63}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Unicode characters, you can specify the encoding in the call to `getBytes`:

```
byte arr[] = S.getBytes("UTF8");
```

As far as why you are getting `63` as a result, the call to `getBytes` without a parameter uses your platform's default encoding. The character `\u9999` cannot be properly represented in your default encoding, so that gets turned into `?` which in ASCII has the decimal value `63`.

Comment: Absolutely correct.  See also: [Why new String(bytes, enc).getBytes(enc) does not return the original byte array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544965/why-new-stringbytes-enc-getbytesenc-does-not-return-the-original-byte-array)

Answer (score 1):

It's about the default charset. It may have something to do with the encoding of your java file.

(On my machine, when I compile java file with encoding of cp1252, `getBytes()` seems to also use cp1252 as default charset. Since cp1252 doesn't support the unicode character, it becomes a `?` character, i.e. `63`. When I compile java with encoding of UTF-16, `getBytes()` returns the data `0x9999` as expected.)

> The behavior of this method when this string cannot be encoded in the
>   default charset is unspecified.
>   (Source: [`getBytes()` from oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html))

My suggestion is to simply use `"\u9999".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE)` (or `UTF_16BE`) to get the 2-byte array you desire. So there is no need to be concerned about encoding of java source. The array should be `{-103,-103}`.

`byte` with value of `-103` is represented in memory as `0x99`.