# Pass data of non english character to web server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

From html , i am using data of non english characters to controller.
eg) passing multi章byte in url as post request.

But in controller data is receiving as

multiç« byte

Can any one help me on how to fix this issue?

Comment: What is the character encoding of the form?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to tell the browser that you're serving UTF-8 content and expecting UTF-8 submit. You can do that by either placing the line in the very top of your JSP,

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

or by adding the following entry to `web.xml` so that you don't need to repeat `@page` over all JSPs:

```xml
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Then, you need to tell the servlet API to use UTF-8 to parse POST request parameters. You can do that by creating a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which does basically the following:

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    // ...
}
```

That's all. You do **not** need `<form accept-charset>` (that would make things worse when using MSIE browser) and you do **not** necessarily need `<meta http-equiv="content-type">` (that's only interpreted when the page is served from local disk file system instead of over HTTP).

Beware that when you're using `System.out.println()` or a logger in order to verify the submitted value, that it should in turn also be configured to use UTF-8 to present the characters, otherwise you will be mislead by still being presented with [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in your action method

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

this must be called prior to any `request.getParameter()` call

and just change the encoding depending on your needs

you can also refer to this

[HttpServletRequest - setCharacterEncoding seems to do nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278900/httpservletrequest-setcharacterencoding-seems-to-do-nothing)

[request.getQueryString() seems to need some encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029401/java-servlet-and-utf-8-problem)

Comment: can you tell me what worst thing happened?

Comment: value "multi章byte" is passed to server. but in server, it is receiving as "multiç« byte"

Comment: it is passed as POST? and read using `request.getParameter()`?

Comment: yes, it is passed as POST  and read using request.getParameter()