# How to process encoded unicode text in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, unicode, urldecode

I am hitting my servlet URL from external source. One of the parameter is having Hindi text. The external source is encoding it. The encoded value is.

```
%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%20%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%97
```

I can see it in TCP dump via wireshark. But I am not getting this encoded string in servlet application. I am trying to get it via getParameter() method. It's returning some random characters.

Since I am not getting correct value, so if I try to decode it in my servlet class with the use of

```
URLDecoder.decode(myString, "UTF-8");
```

Then it's returning some random characters, like this -

```
à¤µà¤¿à¤·à¤¯ à¤µà¤¸à¥�à¤¤à¥�
```

Please suggest me how to read in servlet this encoded text and decode back to original value.

Comment: `URLDecode.decode` does not print anything.

Comment: I made the edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am trying to get it via getParameter() method.

`getParameter` and handling of input encodings in Servlet is broken in general. You get ISO-8559-1 whether you want it or not (and you generally don't).

You can work around this and get UTF-8 for query string parameters by:

1. Container-specific configuration options (eg Tomcat `URIEncoding`).
2. Grabbing the raw `request.getQueryString()` and passing its pieces into `URLDecoder.decode(..., "utf-8")` manually instead of relying on `getParameter`. Only if you are taking this route do you need to worry about `URLDecoder` yourself.
3. Fixing up the mis-decoding of the `getParameter` output by encoding the bad value back to the original bytes it came from (using ISO-8859-1) and then decoding it as UTF-8, eg `new String(request.getParameter("param").getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "utf-8")`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029401/java-servlet-and-utf-8-problem) for background.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this:

```
try {
    System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode("%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%20%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%97", "UTF-8"));
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

... and it works for me, Hindi characters, no exception thrown.

Make sure your console is outputting in UTF-8, it's probably in a different encoding.

**Edit**

In Eclipse:

Run

Run Configurations...

"Commmon" tab

Encoding

[select UTF-8]

**Edit II**

Example code in the processRequest of your HttpServlet class:

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
String argument = request.getParameter("argument");
String decoded;
if (argument != null) {
    decoded = URLDecoder.decode(argument, "UTF-8");
}
else {
    decoded = "null";
}
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
try {
    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>Servlet TestServlet</title>");            
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h1>The argument's value is: " + decoded + "</h1>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
} finally {            
    out.close();
}
```

Output:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. But sorry for the confusion. In Eclipse, I can see the exact value, but in my application servlet I am unable to get the exact String send by external application. So how to read it exactly? Is there any way to read byte by byte or something?

I made the edit in question. Please check now.

Comment: @user1985957 see my 2nd edit... Inside the `processRequest` method of your `Servlet`, it reads the argument called "argument" through the `getParameter` method and prints it out. Could it simply be that you forgot to set the content-type and charset of the response?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed my process to get content by calling method `getQueryString();`
Since I need to store this value, and then after sometime depending on the provided input from user, I need to  display it to user. `getQueryString()` is returning the encoded string.