# Decode UTF-8 Characters in Apache commons file upload

Tags: java, servlets, utf-8, apache-commons-fileupload

I want to decode UTF-8 charter in servlet for that I followed [this stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212353/how-to-process-encoded-unicode-text-in-servlet)

But this is not working with Apache commons file upload. I have tried like shown below

```
           if (item.getFieldName().equals("matter")) {

                 matter = item.getString();
                 matter = URLDecoder.decode(matter, "UTF-8");
                 System.out.println(matter);
             }
```

This gives out put like

```
    à°¨à°¾à°¯à±?à°¡à±?à°ªà±?à°? à°?à±?à°¨à±?: à°
```

I have tried this with simple request.getParameter(With out Commons fileupload) it worked fine.

How can I do this with Apache commons file upload.