# How to retrieve URDU dataاردو (UTF-8) from HTML form for Insertion into MYSQL Database using Servlets

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, servlets, utf-8

Scenario:
I have MYSQL having default as UTF-8.
Same is the case with my HTML and JSP pages,they all have UTF-8 as their standard.
If I keep the form method as:

form     action  =  "reg"   method   =  "post"   accept-charset  = " ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.5"    enctype  =  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  name   =  "form1" id="form1"
^-------- It works

IF
form     action   =  "reg"   method  =  "post" accept-charset=" ISO-8859-1" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  name="form1" id="form1"

^--------------It works

If
form     action   =   "reg" method   =   "post"     accept-charset   =   "utf-8"        enctype   =     "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"       name   =   "form1"   id=   "form1"
^-------It doesn't work and instead wildcard like characters are displayed.

PROBLEM STATEMENT:
When I redirect HTML page to JSP page and use <% out.println( request.getParameter("name"));%>
It displays correctly : جنید

But, when I use    String xx=request.getParameter("name");
and then display the string it displays :  &#1580 ; &#1606 ;&#1740 ;&#1583 ;

so, except for hard-code, I am not able to put urdu in my database.

I need a solution for:
Taking user input from HTML form in URDU e.g: جنید
and inserting the same جنید in the database and not  &#1580 ;&#1606 ;&#1740 ;&#1583 ; which also corresponds to جنید

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late reporting.

The problem was solved by removing the enctype attribute in the form.

Now, i am able to put data in the database and retrieve as well!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `String xx=request.getParameter("name");` in place of this  you can use `String xx= new String(request.getParameter("name"),"<Proper-Encoding>");`

Then your `String` object `xx` will not get corrupt.

OR

You can use `String xx = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("name"),"<Proper-Encoding>")`

You are getting correct value by printing `request.getParameter("name")` because the servlet container already encodes it for you in proper format. And `out` which is writer in JSP decodes in correct format.

So to save the `request.getParameter("name")` value in `xx` you will have to decode it yourself.

You can refer below links for very clear understanding.

[Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824504/jsp-not-suppported-by-utf-8-encoding)

[Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3029405/2327625)

[Blog](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#JSPServletRequest)

Comment: @Juni okay.. But do post the solution when you find it.