# Servlet Request parameters with utf-8

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, utf-8, weblogic

i am trying to get UTF-8 string with using servlet, my code block is showing below;

```
 request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
 response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

but I could not get the utf-8 string , interesting chars is apperaing...
Is there any way to get UTF-8 string ?

Comment: Which servlet container are you using?

Comment: This is similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029401/java-servlet-and-utf-8-problem

Comment: How are the parameters passed to your servlet, form submit, AJAX, ? Are you passing UTF-8 characters?, what do you meain by "chars is appearing"

Comment: I am pasing "barış" to jsp page with using text field, it is apperaing: barÃÂ±ÃÂ, String text = request.getParameter("text");

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that the string received by the servlet is not really in UTF-8. Make sure that the JSP calling the servlet is also in UTF-8. Try adding this at the top of your JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Comment: It is not working, i am using text-filed inside the enctype= multipart/form-data , is there any affects

Comment: `multipart/form-data` is mainly used to upload files. If you want help we would need to see more of your code.