# Parsing HTTP query string in Java

Tags: java, http, parsing

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Query String Manipulation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128436/query-string-manipulation-in-java)
>   [Parsing query strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-in-java)

I have a string similar to `name1=value&name2=value&name3=value`.  I need to parse this into a map of some sort so I can get at the individual values.  I've been googling how to do this, but have come up with many, many different solutions.  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: This depends on your definition of **best**. Fastest to run? Easiest to program? Easiest to understand?

Comment: @Bert: I'll take a look, maybe it will help me out.

Comment: @Paulo:  Probably easiest to program, I want to keep my code as simple as possible.