# Regular expression statements (replaceAll)

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to Java and Regex. I have been looking at this regular expression below and do not seems to understand. This is simply to get session key and hope someone can explain to me.

Here is the url

```
URL: http://somewebsite.com/signin?SessionKey=HDGshCWo3J0000000ED6
```

Here is the code

```
String sessionKey = url.replaceAll("^.*SessionKey=([^&]*).*$", "$1");
System.out.println(sessionKey);
```

Result

```
HDGshCWo3J0000000ED6
```

My questions are below
For regex

```
^.*SessionKey=([^&]*).*$
```

1. What is the purpose of . (any char) and *(Match 0 or more times) after ^
2. Why not just use ^SessionKey=
3. ([^&]*) - Why grouping is used here and what is &?
4. .*$ - Why use . and * before end of line?

For replacement

1. $1 - What is $1?

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer >> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ **AND** http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Comment: Have you looked here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: Pure `regex` part you should be able to figure out for yourself. Just keep in mind that URL does not **start** with "SessionKey" string.

Comment: This `replaceAll` is more of a shorthand for the purpose of getting the matched text. Normally, you would have to write with Matcher.find() and if statement. I personally don't like this shorthand, but other people may disagree.

Comment: Thanks for helping newbie :) I've been reading oracle regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the regex `^.*SessionKey=([^&]*).*$`:

> 1) What is the purpose of . (any char) and *(Match 0 or more times) after ^

`^` means start of expression, it will match the beginning of the `String`. This allows anything before the the `SessionKey` word.

> 2) Why not just use ^SessionKey=

Explained above. This would not allow words before `SessionKey`.

> 3) ([^&]*) - Why grouping is used here and what is &?

`&` is the literal `&`. This part will match everything until it finds the literal `&`. Grouping is used so the value can be retrieved with `$1` (explained below).

> 4) .*$ - Why use . and * before end of line?

`.*$` will basically ignore everything after the `&` till the end of the `String`.

> $1 - What is $1?

That means first group matched. In your regex, it is the content matched inside the first `()`, that is `[^&]*`.

Comment: Thanks for details answer, that clears up most of questions :)

Comment: What are the questions left?

Comment: Actually no more questions left. I fully understand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sessionKey = url.replaceAll("^.*SessionKey=([^&]*).*$", "$1");
```

Will replace the the match by `"^.*SessionKey=([^&]*).*$"` with the first captured group `$1` which is `([^&]*)`.

Your questions:

1. `.*` will essentially match all characters it can up until `Sessionkey`, as an example, we find what `.*` matches in `"no hello"` when used in the context `(.*)hello`. It's purpose is to consume any characters which may be in the query string until we reach `SessionKey` after which point we ***know*** how to extract the value we want.

> ```
> >>> grep(r'(.*)hello','no hello')
> ['no ']
> ```

1. `^SessionKey=` would have to have a query string of the form `SessionKey=`, the `^` anchor means to look at the beginning of the string. A normal query string would be like `www.site.com/somewith?...`
2. `([^&]*)` here is used to match anything which isn't an `&`. When a `^` is found as the first charcter in a character class `[...]`, it means the inversion of what is in the class, so `[^&]` matches everything **but** `&`. This is used to capture the session key's value.
3. `.*$` will consume any characters left over after the session key's value.

The capture from the whole expression `$1` replaces the string `sessionKey` with itself, resulting in sessionKey equalling the capture of `([^&]*)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Henny, hello example just certainly makes me understand more :)

Comment: @user2388556 glad it helped. You should accept whichever answer helped you the most so other's who view your question know which was the most relevant answer (or at least what helped answer your q. the most)

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have covered the main question of how the regex works, so I am not going to repeat them.

I just want to note that the code will return the original string when `SessionKey` key is not found in the query string.

Another potential problem is that, if there are some key named `SecondarySessionKey`, and depending on the position in the URL, you might get the value of `SecondarySessionKey` instead of `SessionKey`.

A safer approach would be to use `URL` or `URI` class to pick out the query string, then [parse the query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128436/query-string-manipulation-in-java).

Comment: Thanks for your answer nhahtdh, I'll def remember about SecondSessionKey scenario.