# Regular expression replace from founded keyword to next &

Tags: java, regex

I am no friend of questions without any code but I have absolutely no idea how to search for this issue.

I got a String like this with a couple of key/value pairs: `test=39&test2=4&test3=10`

and an update String like `test2=5`

now I want to call the `String.replaceAll` method with an expression that replaces the above String with `test2=5` so I get `test=39&test2=5&test3=10`

```
String lTest = "test=39&test2=4&test3=10";
String lUpdate = "test2=5";
Assert.assertEquals("test=39&test2=5&test3=10",lTest.replace(lTest,???regex???);
```

`lUpdate` can be `test` or `test2` or `test3`. the value behind the = can be a number between 0 and 1000.

How can I manage this with regular expression?

Thx a lot for your help.

**UPDATE!!!** 
this works like a charme(thx to user laune):

```
@Test
public void test(){
  String lResult = update("test1=1234&test2=4949&test3=1", "test2=42");
  assertEquals("test1=1234&test2=42&test3=1", lResult);

  lResult = update("test1=1234&test2=4949&test3=1", "test3=5");
  assertEquals("test1=1234&test2=4949&test3=5", lResult);

  lResult = update("test1=1234&test2=4949&test3=1", "test1=100");
  assertEquals("test1=100&test2=4949&test3=1", lResult);
}

static String update(String str, String upd) {
  // split to get the keyword and the value
  String[] kwv = upd.split("=");
  // compose the regex
  String regex = "(?<=^|&)" + Pattern.quote(kwv[0]) + "=\\d+";
  return str.replaceAll(regex, upd);
}
```

Comment: `s.replace( "test=39&test2=4&test3=10", "test=39&test2=5&test3=10")` or even `s.replace( "test2=4&", "test2=5&")` would do what you *describe*. If this isn't what you *want*, you'll have to improve your description. (What is variable, what not?)

Comment: Is it always going to be the middle value?

Comment: See [Query String Manipulation in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128436/query-string-manipulation-in-java) as it looks like you are working with a query string and I dont know JAVA but I know you need something more like an object then a string for this type of data manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex should be constructed from the update string. I use negative lookbehind so that even keywords with, say, an embedded hyphen would work.

```
static String update( String str, String upd ){
    // split to get the keyword and the value
    String[] kwv = upd.split( "=" );
    // compose the regex
    String regex = "(?<=^|&)" + Pattern.quote(kwv[0]) + "=\\d+";
    return str.replaceAll( regex, upd );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this

```
String lTest = "test=39&test2=4&test3=10";
String lUpdate = "test2=5";

String name = lUpdate.split("=")[0]; //test2
lTest = lTest.replaceAll("\\b"+name+"=\\d+", lUpdate);
```

Since `name` will be `test2` regex will look like `\btest2=\d+`.

- `\b` is [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) which will prevent regex engine from matching `test2` in `Footest2`
- `\d+` represents one or more digit so it should be able to match numbers from range 0-1000 as pointed in your question.

---

In case `name` in `name=value` pair could contain some special characters like `+` or `%` which could be also regex metacharacteres, you should escape them. Easiest way to do so would be using `Pattern.quote(name)`.
Also non alphabetic characters (or digits) like `%` will break approach with word boundary `\b` because `\btest2` can be matched also for `foo%test2` since `%` is not considered as word characters. In that case we need more precise test to check if `name` is placed after `&` character or [start of the string](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (`^`). In other words we need to use [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) `(?<=&|^)`

So your code can be something like

```
lTest = lTest.replaceAll("(?<=&|^)"+Pattern.quote(name)+"=\\d+", lUpdate);
```

Comment: Might also be a good idea to add \Q and \E delimiters around the interpolated variable name for robustness. (Should the variable contain special regex symbols itself).

Comment: @user268396 `\Q` and `\E` may also have few problems if name will start with `\E` and end with `\Q` for instance. `Pattern.quote(name)` would be better, but since I don't know if input will come from keybord or from predefined data I decided to skip this part for now.

Comment: Agreed, Pattern.quote() is the way to go.

Comment: @user268396 Added to answer but I am not sure if it will be needed, based on "`lUpdate` can be `test` or `test2` or `test3`" from question.

Comment: I regret to say that your solution is inconsistent. You take pains for matching literal magics (like .*?+) in the "keyword", but then you risk lots of non-\w characters such as -:!% which are just as likely to occur.

Comment: @StefanBeike Since our solutions are the same it is kind of strange, but I don't mind :)

Comment: sorry. launes only benefit was to put it in a method... but I give you +1

Comment: @StefanBeike How you wrap this code is entirely up to you. You can place it in method (static or not), or even in constructor. What is important is what code *does*. But again which answer you want to accept is based on your preference so as long as you pick correct (working) solution I don't mind which one you chose.

Comment: yeah I know I am so sorry

Answer (score 1):

create a new string which looks like 
`lTest "\n" lUpdate`
then use this pattern

```
^([^=]+)=(\d+)\n(.*?)\1=\d+
```

and replace w/

```
$3$1=$2
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/178)

Answer (score 1):

You will first have to break down your `lUpdate` string into the variable name and value, so you can search for the variable name in `lTest`:

```
String lTest = "test=39&test2=4&test3=10";
String lUpdate = "test2=5";

Matcher assignmentMatcher = Pattern.compile("(.*)=(.*)").matcher(lUpdate);
if (assignmentMatcher.matches()) {
    String varName = assignmentMatcher.group(1);
    String val = assignmentMatcher.group(2);

    String replaced = lTest.replaceFirst(varName + "=[^&]+", varName + "=" + val);
    Assert.assertEquals("test=39&test2=5&test3=10",replaced);
}
```