# Bad character encoding when posting via AJAX

Tags: ajax, encoding, utf-8, dojo, struts2

I've a Struts2 application with some encoding problems. My JSP page displays 2 forms; when I send the first one (a simple, regular form, which reloads the full page), *non-standard characters* such as `á` or `ñ` are sent and shown correctly. However, when I do the same with the second form (which is sent via AJAX), the data gets corrupted (`Ãí`, `Ã!` and so on).

**main.jsp:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    ...
    <s:head theme="ajax"/>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- This form is sent via regular HTTP request -->
    <s:form theme="simple" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <s:textfield key="field1" name="var1"/>
        <s:submit key="send" action="SAVE_ACTION"/>
    </s:form>
    <div id="ajaxContainer">
         <jsp:include file="ajax-part.jsp"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**ajax-part.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!-- This form is sent via AJAX -->
<s:form enctype="multipart/form-data" theme="ajax" action="AJAX_ACTION" acceptcharset="UTF-8">
    <s:textfield key="field2" name="var2"/>
    <s:submit key="send" targets="ajaxContainer"/>
</s:form>
```

As you can see, I've set UTF-8 encoding everywhere. I've also checked that the files are actually UTF-8 encoded. And DOJO (which is used for the AJAX requests) is configured in UTF-8 too, because `<s:head theme="ajax"/>` becomes:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    // Dojo configuration
    djConfig = {
        baseRelativePath: "/myApp/struts/dojo",
        isDebug: false,
        bindEncoding: "UTF-8",
        debugAtAllCosts: false
    };
</script>
```

I'm running the application on a Tomcat 6 server; adding the `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` parameter makes no difference (appart from the log files being recorded in UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1).

It happens both in Google Chrome and IE8, so I guess the browser has nothing to do with the problem, it must be something in the webapp.

What am I missing? What can I change to process correctly my AJAX posts?

Comment: What happens if you remove acceptcharset="UTF-8" from <s:form/>? And also try removing bindEncoding: "UTF-8" from the ajax too?

Comment: Without acceptcharset="UTF-8" it seems to work just the same way. As for the bindEncoding parameter for the DOJO configuration, I don't know how to remove or change it..

Comment: Struts2 dojo has been deprecated (I forget when but by 2.2.1 it definitely has).  I don't think it is server side because you can post your data correctly with a normal form.  The same interceptor stack is used my guess is how dojo is preparing the url.  Perhaps manage the ajax manually (jQuery and similar javascript libraries).

Comment: Have you inspected the ajax request with firebug?

Comment: Thanks for the Firebug tip, Quaternion. Finally I was able to solve the problem :) Although I'd like to have a better solution...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved!

After inspecting AJAX requests with Firebug (thanks for the tip, *Quaternion*) I found out the problem: Dojo was sending correctly the data in GET requests, with the parameters URL-encoded. First I thought that Struts2 was doing the URL-decoding with the wrong charset, thus corrupting the data; but as *Steven Benitez* pointed out, it was actually the underlying Servlet API.

The problem was finally solved by setting `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` to the `<Connector>` on Tomcat's server.xml, as explained in [Apache Tomcat FAQs](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q2).

In case this approach doesn't work for somebody else, it could also be *manually solved* by adding the following conversion where the AJAX data is received:

```
new String(myData.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Struts2 doesn't URL decode. The underlying Servlet API does. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469874/how-do-i-correctly-decode-unicode-parameters-passed-to-a-servlet

Comment: Your link led me to this page http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q2 - which I've immediately bookmarked. It seems that I've finally found how to read the GET data in the correct encoding :). I'll have to wait 'til next monday to test it, but it should work. Thanks a lot!!