# How to escape # symbol in url?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I had # symbol to pass as parameter in my URL. But it is discarding all the parameter values after #. Kindly suggest me solution. Following is my url

```
GetConnectiont?   
  customerID=customer1&activenode=Sv50&parent=server&frame=imHealthCheckFrame&
connectedFrom=healthCheck&username=root&password=anil#1234&fromAskUsrPwd=askPassword
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you reading that parameter in your Servlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to encode the parameters that may contain `#` and then decode back the parameter in server side code.

You can use many resources in the internet to URL-encode strings, like [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/). In your case, `anil#1234` becomes `anil%231234`.

Answer (score 10):

Per the answer found here: [How to escape Hash character in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007352/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-url)

Replace `#` with `%23`.

You can find a list of all the reserved characters here: [Percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

---

**A word on JavaScript encoding**

[`encodeURI(str)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

> "Assumes that the URI is a complete URI, so does not encode reserved characters that have special meaning in the URI. `encodeURI` replaces all characters except the following with the appropriate UTF-8 escape sequences:" [[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI#Description)

[`encodeURIComponent(str)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

> "Escapes all characters except the following: alphabetic, decimal digits, - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )" [[2]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#Description)

In your case, you would use `encodeURIComponent()`, only on your query string, to escape any and all reserved chracters.

```
!  %21 
#  %23 
$  %24 
&  %26 
'  %27 
(  %28 
)  %29 
*  %2A 
+  %2B 
,  %2C 
/  %2F 
:  %3A 
;  %3B 
=  %3D 
?  %3F 
@  %40 
[  %5B 
]  %5D
```

Comment: If i replace # with %23, do i need to replace %23 with # symbol while getting that parameter in the servlet?

Comment: Possibly define a character encoding scheme on your servlet? http://stackoverflow.com/a/470320/1762224

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the value(if you are using string concatenation to create the url). in javascript you can use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) like

```
encodeURIComponent('anil#1234');//or your variable here
```

Comment: Can you tell me full url that i had given above? Thanks

Comment: @ANILBABU how is the url generated

Comment: it takes inputs from the user and creates a URL. THe input from the user may contain special characters.

Comment: I have already shared my url in the post...... Can you please see it once and suggest a solution? @arun P Johny

Comment: @ANILBABU what I'm asking is the script which is generating the url