# Correct URL encoding of # Java WebClient

Tags: java, spring-webclient

I'm tring to use this code to retrieve data from my API:

```
        Mono<String> client = WebClient.builder()
          .baseUrl("https://localhost:8081/getPost/" + id) // or URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8")
          .defaultHeaders(new Consumer<HttpHeaders>() {
              @Override
              public void accept(HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
                httpHeaders.addAll(createHeaders());
              }
            })
          .build()
          .get()
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToMono(String.class);
```

My Ids starts with '#' so if I use this code it will result in:

```
https://localhost:8081/getPost/#id1
```

The problem is that I need it url encoded so it should be getPost/%23id1, I tried to use URLEncoder on id but the result is double encoded:

```
 https://localhost:8081/getPost/%25%23id1
```

I need to get rid of that %25

Comment: I am sorry but I think you can't .. The %23 is due the fact # is a [reserved character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) (some reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007352/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-url) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787525/how-to-escape-symbol-in-url)). Hope I helped you

Comment: I know that # is reserved but if I use the code above the url will result in /#id while I need /%23id. I'm using the same API on php and I encode # with %23. I don't know why Java allows # char without encoding

Comment: Sorry I didn't get to the point but you were very clear.
This behaviour is very strange. I have tried to reproduce your code [here](https://replit.com/talk/share/example/134965) and it seems to work. %25 stands for %, is there something like that in your id string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems strange that `WebClient.builder().baseUrl` fails to correctly encode the reserved character "#". If you look at the doc, it says it's equivalent to `.uriBuilderFactory(new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(baseUrl))`. Therefore, you can do your own URL encoding, but suppress it in WebClient:

```
DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(
        "https://localhost:8081/getPost/" + URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8"));
factory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.URI_COMPONENT);
Mono<String> client = WebClient.builder()
          .uriBuilderFactory(factory)
          .defaultHeaders(...)
          .build()
          ...etc...
```

Comment: For those who may be wondering: the `DefaultUriBuilderFactory` class has a no-args constructor, so it is possible to instantiate one without needing to pass in a `baseUrl`.