# What's the difference between "URIEncoding" of Tomcat, Encoding Filter and request.setCharacterEncoding

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, encoding, utf-8

There may be many ways to solve encoding problem:

- Encoding filter like [Spring MVC UTF-8 Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding)
- Setting URIEncoding=UTF-8 in server.xml of Tomcat , like http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/how-to-support-utf-8-uriencoding-with-tomcat.html.
- request.setCharacterEncoding( utf-8 )

Today, I have a problem that path param is not decoded well like

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/context/method/{key}",method=RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json;charset=utf-8")
public String method(@PathVariable String key){

    logger.info("key="+key+"------------");
}
```

I can see that the key is decoded bad! If I pass a word `"新浪"` from the front end, it will become `"æ°æµª"`. I write the below code to examine if the server is decoding this with "ISO-8859-1":

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String key="新浪";
    byte[] bytes=key.getBytes("UTF-8");
    String decode=new String(bytes,"ISO-8859-1");
    System.out.println(decode);
}
```

And it comes out with the same output `"æ°æµª"`. so indeed, the path variable is decoded with ISO-8859-1.

And then I try to add a filter to my `web.xml` to solve this problem:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

But the same garbled.

Until I set below to my `server.xml`

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"   ----Here is Added
/>
```

And it works for this even I remove the filter.

But I am still very confusing about the encoding issue. And besides , this is only GET method, if it is POST method, I guess the solution will probably be different

Can anybody please explain that what difference encoding solution should we take for what kind of problem ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

- `CharacterEncodingFilter` configures encoding of request body. That is, it affects encoding of `POST` request parameters, etc, but doesn't affect encoding of `GET` parameters
- `URIEncoding` is used to specify encoding of the URI, therefore it affects `GET` parameters
- `useBodyEncodingForURI="true"` tells Tomcat to use encoding configured for request body when decoding URIs. So, as far as I understand,  if you set `CharacterEncodingFilter` and `useBodyEncodingForURI="true"` then you don't need `URIEncoding`.

In practice, you need to two things to solve possible problems with encoding of parameters:

- `CharacterEncodingFilter` for `POST` requests
- `URIEncoding` (or `useBodyEncodingForURI="true"`) for `GET` requests

Comment: 1.what about `request.setCharacterEncoding`  2. I read a book that in `GET` method, the pathvar and query string(URL) is decoded separately. Therefore, we need , and URIEncoding is for URI(path var), and `useBodyEncodingForURI` is for query string on URL..Is this book wrong?

Answer (score 0):

for tomcat7

- **CharacterEncodingFilter** configures encoding of **request body**. That is, it affects encoding of POST request parameters, etc, but doesn't affect encoding of GET parameters
- **useBodyEncodingForURI="true"** tell tomcat to use **CharacterEncoding( can be set by CharacterEncodingFilter)** to parse QueryString. it's affect GET request parameter .
- **URIEncoding** to parset URI , default is ISO-8859-1.

for tomcat8

- default UTF-8.